# What is the best way to show large UIView on UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have an large `UIView`. Its variable size. It may be larger than 5000x5000 `size`. I draw lines, circles on it using `UIBezierPath`. Also I add some `view`'s on it. Each of these `subview`'s contains `buttons`, `textview`, `labels`, etc.

I placed this main view on `UIScrollView`. `UIScrollView` is `zoomable` and have to show the contents very sharply (It should not get blurred).

Currently, I draw complete `UIView` and added on `UIScrollView`. The problem is that, Its taking too much `memory` and `crashing` because of `Memory Pressure Issue.`

How should I handle this to achieve high performance?

Comment: Your views need to be changed at runtime or you are building a large image that doesn't need to be changed?

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida, I need both, at first load my view will be constant but it can change on user's interaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass UIView and implement the `+layerClass` method in it:

```
+layerClass
{
    return [CATiledLayer class];
}
```

This causes your view to be backed by `CATiledLayer` instead of a single, huge `CALayer` (which would consume too much memory at that size).

Then you just implement `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` in your custom view class and do all of your drawing in there.  I had to do this recently in my project which uses UIScrollViews to scroll over an area that can be as big as 10000 x 150000.

Comment: Hi Jeff, If I have a UIView of size 6000X6000 having some drawing by using UIBezierPath(in drawRect:), how should I tiling with it? Please give some hint.

Comment: If you're already doing your drawing in drawRect, you shouldn't have to do anything except implement the `+layerClass` method as shown.  The tiling will happen automagically, and your `drawRect` will get called for each tile as it scrolls into view

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestion. Will appreciate your help in future also.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can use tiling with `CATiledLayer`, to lower the memory pressure, but it all depends about what you are loading, when, and some other aspects.
Tiling is a complex topic, you can find more info [here](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html#_tiling)