# UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions using very high memory usage

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, swift4, uigraphicscontext

I am setting up a very high resolution image as background of UIView. For this I am using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions. Here is my code:

```
self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: self.backgroundImage!)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize,false,
backgroundImage?.draw(in:CGRect.init(x:0, y: 0, width:imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height))
backgroundImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Background image width = 2481.0 and height = 3509.0. Before setting this my app memory usage is 60 MB but as soon as I call this memory consumption bump up to 500 MB. I don't want to compromise with image quality and  resolution.

Comment: And what is `imageSize`? For the resolution you posted the memory usage should not be larger then 50MB per image so 440MB is enough to have 10 such images. Anyway these buffers are pretty costly and you might need to find a different tool to manage them with less memory consumption. Maybe you might be able to tile the image and use RGBA data directly on some file. Then try to merge tile files into a single RGBA raw file which may be used to encode it to JPEG or PNG. But I do not guarantee this would actually reduce the memory consumption since it depends on the provided tools again.

Comment: imageSize is 2481*3509

Comment: Well using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 2481, height: 3509), true, 1.0)` used 35MB in my case. But using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 2481, height: 3509), true, 0.0)` (note that 0.0 at the end) used 130MB. So if you are using `0.0` the system will use screen scale which means it will further greatly increate the size of your image. To be fair you need to use `image.scale`.

Comment: I found solution for this. It is happening due to high resolution image load in a UIView. To manage memory there is solution CATiltedLayer. I found solution from 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961577/what-is-the-best-way-to-show-large-uiview-on-uiscrollview
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961577/what-is-the-best-way-to-show-large-uiview-on-uiscrollview
You can get more details related to this on 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/169004/calayer-tutorial-ios-getting-started